# 7zip can't unpack file it created

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I have a task running nightly at some remote locations that uses 7zip to compress a file and ftp it to my host.  I am having trouble unpacking it using the command line at the host, it says

```
Unsupported Method Sub Items Errors:1
```

It is unpacking .zip files just fine, and I can manually open the 7z files with 7zip and extract them just fine, but the command line is returning the same error for any file created with 7zip.  (I have to use 7zip for these sites because they are 64 bit and pkzip does not work on 64 bit systems).

This is the script I am using.

```
d:
cd brdata
del HOST00*.txt

cd d:\brdftp

:: Set Path Variable
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\


:: Store 1 Unzip and Copy
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

cd d:\brdftp\Store01

echo %PATH%
7z e HOST0001.ZIP
move d:\brdftp\Store01\HOST0001.TXT d:\brdata

:: Store 2 Unzip and Copy
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

cd d:\brdftp\Store02

echo %PATH%
7z e HOST0002.ZIP
move d:\brdftp\Store02\HOST0002.TXT d:\brdata

:: Store 3 Unzip and Copy
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

cd d:\brdftp\Store03

echo %PATH%
7z e HOST0003.ZIP
move d:\brdftp\Store03\HOST0003.TXT d:\brdata

:: Store 4 Unzip and Copy
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

cd d:\brdftp\Store04

echo %PATH%
7z e host0004.7z
move d:\brdftp\Store04\HOST0004.TXT d:\brdata
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the 7zip documentation, the formats that 7zip supports are:

Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP and WIM

Unpacking only: AR, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DMG, EXT, FAT, GPT, HFS, IHEX, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, QCOW2, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, UEFI, VDI, VHD, VMDK, WIM, XAR and Z.

So maybe the format you are trying to pack is not supported by 7zip.